# jQuery Autocomplete plugin pengoworks version not working

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using the jQuery plugin (pengoworks version) and I have a problem...  When I initially type something into the text box it brings up the suggestion box fine.  However, after I type a few letters into the text box, if I pause, and then resume typing it will only filter out, what was populated in the suggestion box beneath, instead of running the query again for new results.  But it WILL rerun the query every time I hit the back key after my initial pause... I hope you can understand what I'm talking about.  Sorry for anything that isn't clear, I am new to programming. I will provide my html page and my php page.

```
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link href="jquery.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#input_box').autocomplete("autocomplete_search.php");

        })
    </script>
   </head>

    <body>

        <input type="text" name="input_box" value="" id="input_box"   />

    </body>
    </html>
```

here is my PHP part.

```
    <?php
    include 'fh.inc.db.php';

    $db = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD) or 
    die ('Unable to connect. Check your connection parameters.');
    mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    $location = htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['q'])); //gets the location of the search

    if(is_numeric($location)) {

       $query = "SELECT
           zipcode_id
       FROM
           user_zipcode
       WHERE
           zipcode_id LIKE '%$location%'
       ORDER BY zipcode_id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

    } elseif(is_string($location)) {

    $query = "SELECT
            city
        FROM
           user_zipcode
       WHERE
           city LIKE '%$location%'
       ORDER BY city DESC LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));


    }


    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    extract($row);
    if(is_numeric($location)){
       echo "$zipcode_id \n";
    }elseif(is_string($location)){
       echo "$city \n"; 
    }

    }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: bug in plugin's initialization**

It seems there is a tricky bug in the plugin that makes the options `matchSubset: 0` you pass ignored and changed to 1.

During initialization, an `options` object is built based on the options passed as second parameter and some default values:

```
...
options.delay = options.delay || 400;
options.matchCase = options.matchCase || 0;
options.matchSubset = options.matchSubset || 1;
...
```

There is a problem with this way of doing and numeric variables: `matchSubset: 0` returns false in a conditional statement ! In our case, `matchSubset` will always be equal to 1 !

I understand why it was done like that though. You use the same notation to check a variable is `undefined` because it returns false as well. But in the case of numeric, it does not work as expected.

If you can't use another plugin, I suggest you to change the way the default options are merged. You can do it like this for instance:

```
//options.matchSubset = options.matchSubset || 1;
options.matchSubset = typeof matchSubset !== undefined
    ? options.matchSubset
    : 1;
```

You could also make a `defaults` object literal and use `$.extend()` to merge the defaults and the options, like this is typically done in jquery plugins.

---

### Initial answer

The plugin by default uses a caching system. If the current query is not in the cache already, the plugin checks if a subset is present.

So let's say you type "Foo", the plugin makes a query and cache the results. Then you add a "t" which results in query "Foot". the plugin won't find an entry for "Foot" but will find one for "Foo" so it will filter this list instead of making a new request.

```
// "q" is the query text
function loadFromCache(q) {
    if (!q) return null;
    if (cache.data[q]) return cache.data[q];
    if (options.matchSubset) {
        for (var i = q.length - 1; i >= options.minChars; i--) {
            var qs = q.substr(0, i);
            var c = cache.data[qs];
            if (c) {
                var csub = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                    var x = c[j];
                    var x0 = x[0];
                    if (matchSubset(x0, q)) {
                        csub[csub.length] = x;
                    }
                }
                return csub;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

You can control this behavior by setting explicitly the option `matchSubset` to zero:

```
$('#input_box').autocomplete("autocomplete_search.php", { matchSubset: 0 });
```

Fromt the [documentation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete_docs.txt):

> **matchSubset (default value: 1)**
>     Whether or not the autocompleter can use a cache for more specific queries. This means that all matches of "foot" are a subset of all matches for "foo". Usually this is true, and using this options decreases server load and increases performance. Remember to set cacheLength to a bigger number, like 10.

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice but it didn't seem to work.  I made this change as per advised but I am still having the same problem.  After I initially type in something, if I pause, only backspacing seems to bring up new query results.  Any more suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  $(document).ready(function() { $('#input_box').autocomplete("autocomplete_search.php",       {matchSubset: 0, CacheLength: 10 });
     
  })

Comment: It seems there is a bug in the plugin. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot it seems that fixed the problem.  Just wanted to make sure that you meant to use "typeof matchSubset !== undefined" instead of "typeof matchSubset != undefined" and what is the difference?  thanks again.

Comment: "===" and "!==" are the strict (in)equality operators ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators))

Comment: Great link thanks! I decided to use jQuery UI for my autocompleting needs and am finding myself unable to get even basic functionality working. If you happen to be a pro at that as well feel free to comment on the question I just posted.  Thanks again for all your help!